# I'm trying to transpose some columns of my table to row. I'm using pyspark.sql

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to transpose some columns of my table to row. I'm using pyspark.sql

My Initial Dataframe:

[image: **InputTable**]

I want transposed Dataframe like this:

[image: **OutTable**]

Kindly give me some solution how can I do this?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer : [Format to Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Solution to question :

***Instead of transpose use a simple where clause .***

Try :

Create an empty data frame DF2 with columns as email,fax,phone

and use below code snippet for each column :

```
DF2 = DF2.withColumn("email",DF1.select('phone_number').where(DF1['phone_role'] == 'EMAIL'))

DF2 = DF2.withColumn("fax",DF1.select('phone_number').where(DF1['phone_role'] == 'FAX'))

DF2 = DF2.withColumn("phone",DF1.select('phone_number').where(DF1['phone_role'] == 'PHONE'))
```

Later you can drop DF1 .

Comment: Thank you for your response , but i am new with pyspark.sql .Can you please explain it more in details.

Comment: DF2 is output you needed. DF2.withColumn creates new column in DF2 , 

DF1.select(['phone_number']).where(DF1['phone_role'] == 'EMAIL') selects rows of column 'phone_number' which has 'EMAIL' within it .

Comment: i am getting error .."col should be Column"
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

schema = StructType([StructField("name_id", StringType(), True), StructField("phone", StringType(), True), StructField("email", StringType(), True), StructField("Fax", StringType(), True), StructField("webpage", StringType(), True)])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

df2 = df2.withColumn("email",df.select(['phone_number']).where(df['phone_role'] == 'EMAIL'))

Comment: sorry , please remove [] inside select 


DF1.select('phone_number').where(DF1['phone_role'] == 'EMAIL')

Comment: again getting same error ."col should be Column"
df2 = df2.withColumn("email",df.select('phone_number').where(df['phone_role'] == 'EMAIL'))

Comment: i think this minor errors should be solved on own . Still Sorry I missed to add a ')' at the end as I am not using IDE .